# haproxy redirect URL path to another path

Tags: path, redirect, haproxy

haproxy version 1.5.18

I want to redirect:

```
/document/(.*)/(.*)/somefile => /anotherPath/somefile
```

For example: redirect

```
 /document/20181/20182/a_good_pic.jpg => /anotherPath/a_good_pic.jpg
```

How to do that with haproxy?

I retried follow the example for reqirep like:

```
# replace "/static/" with "/" at the beginning of any request path.
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /static/(.*)     \1\ /\2
```

But my example has two parts in URL path that are different to the example, so I got confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions to more than one site.  https://serverfault.com/q/950831/153161

Comment: Is there a reason you are using HAProxy 1.5? It's only receiving critical patches at this point and not part of long term support. Using 1.6 or later will make what you're attempting to do much easier.

Comment: Yes, usually the version is determined by IT people and we have no permission to upgrade them.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare an acl and then do a conditional use_backend statement. Like this:

```
frontend a-frontend-conf

    # Declare an ACL using path_beg (Path Begins)
    acl path_images path_beg /images

    # Use backend server1 if acl condition path_images is fulfilled
    use_backend server1 if path_images

backend server1
    [...]
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/659793/haproxy-how-to-balance-traffic-within-directory-reached

Comment: yes but the some_path part can be any string. So it is not possible to use acl to define the conditional check.

Comment: With that instance, you would use an ACL with the -m reg option, and use regex to compensate for that.

Please see:

https://serverfault.com/questions/388937/how-do-i-match-a-wildcard-host-in-acl-lists-in-haproxy

For additional information on ACL with wildcards.